# Servlet Therad Safety

Tags: jakarta-ee, concurrency, oracle11g, thread-safety

I recently used a cross scripting technique where i inserted script tag in the head   element , i used jquery $.('head').append(''); which had a bug and appended the script tag twice , due to which call to server was made twice what.In my server side code i insert data if data is not present for user,When the call happened twice the simultaneous data was update.This means that neither database showed updated data or either java did not pull updated from DB ofcourse there was fraction of second difference between those too.Please let me know how to handle this type of scenario.

Lets take an example where an application is creating users and assigning IDS so in this case if 300 users do the same operation at the same time there would be data corruption.So how to handle this.

Comment: We would need a more concrete scenario. To avoid duplicate data, you could for example use a unique constraint in database.

Comment: Its simple scenario where  i am inserting a record in db, before insertion i check if record is present. Lets say i am inserting recored for a userid , with fration of msec there is another call which first check if data is present since data was present db should have retured value where is  the mistake java or db.

Comment: Then use a unique constraint in the database, and one of the transaction trying to insert this element will fail.

Comment: when i made a check for duplicate data why dint the DB return me the result

Comment: Because the two transactions execute in parallel, and don't see the changes done by the other until committed. And even if they did, you could have T1 checking if the row exists (no), T2 checking if the row exists (no), T1 inserting the row, T2 inserting the row. That's a typical race condition between two threads checking then acting.

Comment: does using synchronized in this scenario will help

Comment: It will only help if every inserting goes through this path, and you have a single VM doing it. Add a unique constraint, that's what they're for: guarantee the coherence of the data in the database.

Comment: Single VM , IF i have clustered WAS server setup synchronization willn not help